# How do I compare multiple values against a single variable?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

Is there a shortcut for comparing multiple values such as in the following expression?

`if (choice == "a" || choice == "b" || choice == "c") {do something;}`

I thought about switch statements, but they only work for single values as far as I know.

And what about variable declaration or constants?

`int initialValue = 1, finalValue = 1;`

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911691/switch-multiple-values-in-one-case/12911729?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev and what about if those values are not numerical?

Comment: Any constant value can be used in a `switch` `case`.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev and also, when they have a range of values, they must write it like this `age > 9 && age < 15` rather than just simply having `9 < age < 15` which in my opinion, is much more readable.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay what about a range of values? Probably not good practice to write them one by one. Could I rewrite this `age > 9 && age < 15` as something like this `9 < age < 15` which is much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: You could write `9 < age && age < 15`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1)

```
public static string[] array = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
if(array.Any(x => x == choice))
{
   //Your business logic
}
```

Or you can try [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) with [`.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1),

```
if(array.Any(choice.Contains))
{
   //Your business logic
}
```

---

You can use [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) to store distinct elements and use [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) to figure out `choice` is available in hashet or not

```
public static HashSet<string> array = new HashSet<string>(){"a", "b", "c"};
if(array.Contains(choice))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Implement your business logic");
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U1YA1R)

Comment: `Contains()` would be more concise.

Comment: Consider a `HashSet` and `Contains`.

Comment: @DavidMcNeil, Think about future if you want to extend this if condition then in your approach you need to add one more or condition, but in my solution we need to add just one record to the static array

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the case statements in order to map multiple values to the same action:

```
switch(choice)
{
  case "a":
  case "b":
  case "c":
    // Do something
    break;

  default:
    // Do something else
    break;
}
```

Comment: I guess, this would work for this case, but what about a range of numbers or more values?